# Epsilon-delta proof method

Tags: limits, continuity, epsilon-delta, delta-method

Use the definition of continuity and the formal definition of the limit value
("$\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition") to show the following:
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuous in $x = 0$ and has the property
that if $x\neq 0$ then $f (x) \ge 0$. Then $f(0) \geq 0$.

I don't know where to start and I'm not good at using the formal definition of the limit value. I really appreciate some help :)

Comment: The same question was asked yesterday. Did the two students talk to each other?

Comment: Haha, no, a friend of mine from another university in the country I live in asked if I could add the question here. My friend always forgets the password on this site, and asked if I could post it. So I don't know if they know each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start:

Suppose I told you I had a number $a$.  And I told you  that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there will a number $d \ge 0$ so that $|d-a| <\epsilon$.

I claim that that means $a \ge 0$.

Pf:

Either $a = 0$ or $a < 0$ or $a > 0$.  If $a=0$ we have nothing to prove.  So assume $a \ne 0$.

Let $\epsilon = |a| > 0$ and let $d$ be one of those positive $d$.  Then $|d-a| < |a|$.  If $a < 0$ then $|a|>|d-a| = d + |a| \ge |a|$ which is a contradiction.  So for the claim to be true, we must have $a \ge 0$.

Now to your problem:

Because $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ then by definition.

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta$ so that if $|x-0| = |x| < \delta$ then $|f(x) -f(0)|< \epsilon$.

If $f(0)=0$ we have nothing to prove.  If $f(0) \ne 0$ then $|f(0)| > 0$.

Let $\epsilon = |f(0)|$ and $\delta$ the number that makes it so that if $|x| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(0)| < |f(0)|$.  And let $x: 0 < x < \delta$. ANd we know $f(x) \ge 0$.

Then we have $|f(x) -f(0)| < |f(0)|$.  So by my claim at the start of this post:  $f(0) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Do a proof by contradiction. Assume that $f(0) < 0$ and show that there is a neighborhood $(-\delta, \delta)$ around $0$ such that $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$.

Hint for the proof: take $\epsilon = \frac{|f(0)|}{2}$. It also might help to draw a picture.